# Headphone splitter (active, or with appropriate impedance)

Tags: speakers

I would like to split the output signal from my electronic drum set into two 32-ohm headphones. If I use a plain splitter, I will effectively cut the impedance in half, increasing the required current.

Is there a splitter which is designed with this in mind (an active one, or one which would have additional resistance in series?

I know this may potentially be more related to electronics, but I believe music practitioners can share their own experience.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, for low level outputs, such as headphones, the current change due to impedance is unlikely to cause an issue. If you were wanting to connect many headphones it would probably degrade badly, but for just splitting to a second pair I wouldn't bother with an active circuit - just a normal headphone splitter should do just fine.

Comment: +1 thanks, I thought it probably wouldn't make any difference. When I think about it, it is likely that the output is designed for 8 ohm speakers also, I will check the specs. Since I am using 32 ohm headphones, that would mean I could put 4 of them in parallel and keep the current nominal.